# How to Disable WebRTC in JxBrowser?

Tags: jxbrowser

I am looking to disable the **WebRTC** in **JxBrowser** but I can not, Jx browser is a browser done in Java, the team.
Does anyone have a solution to disable webrtc JxBrowser?
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you need basically ? If you want user will not access camera and mic inside your application then you can look into navigator.getUserMedia() and return null etc

Comment: I need to disable the WebRTC in JxBrowser

Comment: JxBrowser doesn't provide functionality that allows disabling WebRTC because Chromium doesn't have this functionality. If you know how to disable WebRTC in Google Chrome, please let me know.

Comment: I need the same on a per browser instance basis. There are global switches which can replace the video and audio streams with fake ones. This can help if you want to disable it globally: `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-fake-device-for-media-stream